# Is there a way to add an alpha value within geom_image in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to create a plot that has logos mapping to X and Y coordinates. The goal though is have another set of points with the same logos, but with an alpha value so that the logos are more transparent.

Here is a reproducible example. The goal is to have the logos on the left be transparent.

```
library(ggimage)
library(tidyverse)
library(RCurl)

Sample_X1 <- c(1,0,2,3,1)
Sample_X2 <- c(4,5,7,4,3)
Sample_Y <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
Logo <- 'https://i1.pngguru.com/preview/233/348/954/numix-circle-for-windows-rstudio-icon-png-icon-thumbnail.jpg'

data <- data.frame(cbind(Sample_X1, Sample_X2, Sample_Y, Logo))

ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Sample_X1, xend = Sample_X2, y = Sample_Y, yend = Sample_Y), size = 1) +
  geom_image(aes(x = Sample_X1, y = Sample_Y, image = Logo), size = .05) +
  geom_image(aes(x = Sample_X2, y = Sample_Y, image = Logo), size = .05) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = 'Example for Stack Overflow')
```

[image: Sample Output]

Is there a way to accomplish this with ggplot? So far I have only been able to find ways to make background logos transparent, but they aren't able to be mapped to the XY data.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add some expected output / output that you have got? Providing some data makes lot easier to get help here... Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`).

Comment: @massisenergy Updated with reproducible example.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Just ended up going in a different direction with the plot.

Answer (score 4):

The `image_fun` parameter can be used to define how the image should be processed. `image_fx` can be used to set the alpha channel.

```
library(ggplot2)

transparent <- function(img) {
  magick::image_fx(img, expression = "0.5*a", channel = "alpha")
}

ggplot(data.frame(x = runif(10), y = runif(10)), aes(x, y)) +
  ggimage::geom_image(
    image = system.file("extdata/Rlogo.png", package="ggimage"),
    image_fun = transparent,
    size = 0.3
  )
```

[image: plot]