# Add png to {ggplot2} that has transparent background and was rotated via {magick}

Tags: r, ggplot2, imagemagick, transparency, patchwork

While adding a transparent png to a ggplot works fine via [`ggplot2::annotation_custom()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotation_custom.html) (but not via [`patchwork::inset_element`](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/reference/inset_element.html)), there seem to be problems when rotating the image via [`magick::image_rotate()`](https://docs.ropensci.org/magick/reference/transform.html).

Find the reprex below. Does anyone have a solution for this?

<sup>NOTE: While there is some overlap, I do not consider this question to be a duplicate of [R/ggplot2: Add png with transparency info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69699055/r-ggplot2-add-png-with-transparency-info) or [Transparent background graph with ggplot2 in high resolution, R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862292/transparent-background-graph-with-ggplot2-in-high-resolution-r), since the problem here seems to specifically arise due to the image rotation.</sup>

```r
library(magick)
library(patchwork)
library(tidyverse)

url <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/RStudio_logo_flat.svg/2560px-RStudio_logo_flat.svg.png"

img <- magick::image_read(url) %>%
  grid::rasterGrob()

img_rot <- magick::image_read(url) %>%
  magick::image_rotate(30) %>% 
  grid::rasterGrob()

ggplot(tibble(x = 1:3)) +
  aes(x = x, y = x) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_fixed() +
  ggplot2::annotation_custom(img, 1, 2, 2, 3) +
  ggplot2::annotation_custom(img_rot, 2, 3, 2, 3) +
  patchwork::inset_element(img,     0, 0, 0.5, 0.5) +
  patchwork::inset_element(img_rot, 0.5, 0, 1, 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with `ggplot` specifically. The rotate changes the size of the image but does not set the background transparent. The image will always have a rectangular shape. You need to set the background so magick knows what to fill in the newly created space with

```
img_rot <- magick::image_read(url) %>%
  magick::image_background("none") %>% 
  magick::image_rotate(30) %>% 
  grid::rasterGrob()
```